# From algebraic point of view, what are the similarities and differences between these two hypercomplex systems?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, hypercomplex-numbers

I would like to know how compare from the algebraic point of view these two 3-dimensional hypercomplex number systems.

**3-dimensional split-complex numbers**

Take $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Hadamard product. In other words, triplets of numbers with element-wise multiplication.

Now assign $(1,1,1)=1,(-1,1,1)=j, (1,1,-1)=k$.

A number would be written in the form $a+bj+ck$. Algebraically it will be a commutative ring with zero divisors (hence, not a field, but that's OK). For instance $(j-1)(k-1)=0$.

Here is a Mathematica code to experiment with:

```
Unprotect[Power]; Power[0, 0] = 1; Protect[Power];
$Pre = (# /. {j -> {-1, 1, 1}, k -> {1, 1, -1}}) /. {x_, y_, z_} -> 
     x/2 + z/2 + (j (y - x))/2 + (k (y - z))/2 &;
```

Using this code one can see that

$j^2=k^2=1$

$jk=j+k-1$

$\log (j+k+1)=\frac{1}{2} j \log (3)+\frac{1}{2} k \log (3)$

$j^j=j^k=j$

$k^k=k^j=k$

$\sqrt{j+k}=\frac{j}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}$

$0^{j+k}=1-\frac{j}{2}-\frac{k}{2}$

The division formula would be:

$\frac{a_1+b_1 j+c_1 k}{a_2+b_2 j+c_2 k}=\frac{j}{2}  \left(\frac{a_1+b_1+c_1}{a_2+b_2+c_2}-\frac{a_1-b_1+c_1}{a_2-b_2+c_2}\right)+\frac{k}{2}  \left(\frac{a_1+b_1+c_1}{a_2+b_2+c_2}-\frac{a_1+b_1-c_1}{a_2+b_2-c_2}\right)+\frac{a_1+b_1-c_1}{2 \left(a_2+b_2-c_2\right)}+\frac{a_1-b_1+c_1}{2 \left(a_2-b_2+c_2\right)}$

If we add a complex unity $i$, we will get a 6-dimensional number system.

Particularly, we will see that

$i^{j+k}=1-j-k$

and

$\log (j k)=i\pi-\frac{i \pi  j}{2}-\frac{i \pi  k}{2}$

**Triplex numbers**

This is a realization of triplex numbers, described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvI7dGXFgm8).

Here,

$1=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$j=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$k=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Mathematica code:

```
Unprotect[Power]; Power[0, 0] = 1; Protect[Power];
$Pre = (# /. ({j -> {1, E^(2 I \[Pi]/3)}, 
          k -> {1, E^(-2 I \[Pi]/3)}}) /. {x_, y_} -> 
        FullSimplify[(x/3 + Im[y]/Sqrt[3] - Re[y]/3) j + (x/3 - 
             Im[y]/Sqrt[3] - Re[y]/3) k + 
          1/3 (x + y + Conjugate[y])] // FullSimplify // Expand) &;
```

Particularly, we will see that

$j^2=k$, $k^2=j$, $jk=1$

$j^k=-\frac{1}{3} 2 e^{\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{3}}} j+\frac{j}{3}+\frac{1}{3} e^{\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{3}}} k+\frac{k}{3}+\frac{e^{\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{3}}}}{3}+\frac{1}{3}$

$0^{j + k + 1}=-\frac{j}{3}-\frac{k}{3}+\frac{2}{3}$

$\log j = \frac{2 \pi  j}{3 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{2 \pi  k}{3 \sqrt{3}}$

$\log(j+k)=\frac{\pi  j}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{3} j \log (2)-\frac{\pi  k}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{3} k \log (2)+\frac{\log (2)}{3}$

The division formula is

$\frac{a_1+b_1 j+c_1 k}{a_2+b_2 j+c_2 k}=\frac{a_2^2 \left(a+b k+c j\right)-a_2 \left(b_2 \left(a k+b j+c\right)+c_2 \left(a j+b+c k\right)\right)+c_2^2 \left(a k+b j+c\right)-b_2 c_2 \left(a+b k+c j\right)+b_2^2 \left(a j+b+c k\right)}{a_2^3+b_2^3+c_2^3-3 a_2 b_2 c_2}$

and

$N(a+bj+ck)=\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc}$

is the analog of modulus.

If we add the complex unity, we will see that

$i^{j+k}=-\frac{j}{3}-\frac{j}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{k}{3}+\frac{k}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{3}$

---

It looks that the both systems are commutative associative algebras with zero divisors but without nilpotents. Can something be said about their differences from the algebraic point of view?

Comment: By the way, persisting calling these things "hypercomplex" (outside of the context of giving background information) looks a little bit like a hallmark of an amateur.  Sort of like you learned all you know from a 100 year old book and you're not aware the subject is sort of closed now. That's OK if you're OK with giving that impression, but I figured I'd mention it. There isn't any reason not to call these "finite dimensional real algebras."

Comment: @rschwieb well, hypercomplex numbers are a bit more restricted than just real algebras, and the linked video explicitly talks about 3D number system.

Comment: What, in your view, distinguishes them?  This is how they are defined at the wiki, at least!

Comment: @rschwieb my view is a bit different from the majority, but in my view a number system desirably should be commutative (and necessary associative), also it should include the multiplicative unity as one of the basis vectors (so it includes the choice of basis besides isomorphism). So, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a hypercomplex system despite it is isomorphic to the split-complexes.

Comment: Selecting special bases with which to formulate later results is more along the lines of application or so-called "geometric algebra". This goes beyond the algebraic properties of the thing.

Comment: In the division formula for the second system, the indices are not affected to the correct letters : that's not $j_1$ and $j_2$.

Comment: @ogerard thanks, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algebraically speaking, the second one is $\mathbb R\times\mathbb C$.

Being commutative semisimple rings, they would be considered quite tame in the big scheme of ring theory.  One can say, however, they are the only two three-dimensional commutative semisimple $\mathbb R$-algebras.

Here are some differences:

| Trait | $\mathbb R^3 $ | $\mathbb R\times \mathbb C$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| simple modules (isoclasses) | 3 | 2 |
| ideals | 8 | 4 |
| composition length | 3 | 2 |

Comment: The both have two idempotents, yes?

Comment: What about the number of distinct values of the sign function? In split-complex numbers it's 9, in complex is infinite, so I suspect, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it should be 27 and in $\mathbb R\times \mathbb C$ it should be infinite as well, correct?

Comment: @Anixx No, the idempotents correspond to ideals.  The first one has $8$ and the second one has $4$.

Comment: @Anixx I do not understand what sign function you are talking about.

Comment: Heh, the sign function question is related to this discussion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407872/is-the-number-of-values-the-sign-function-can-take-on-a-ring-signedness-of-a For triplexes the sign function is quite huge (not fitting here).

Comment: The sign function on 3d-split complex numbers is simpler than on triplexes, it is $\operatorname{sign}(a+bj+ck)=\frac{1}{2} j (\text{sgn}(a+b+c)-\text{sgn}(a-b+c))+\frac{1}{2} k (\text{sgn}(a+b+c)-\text{sgn}(a+b-c))+\frac{\text{sgn}(a+b-c)}{2}+\frac{\text{sgn}(a-b+c)}{2}$

Comment: @Anixx Huh. I have no idea. I've never heard of or used that particular thing.

Comment: Are there non-semisimple commutative 3d R-algebras?

Comment: @Anixx Of course there are. Like $\mathbb R[x]/(x^3)$.  If you're interested in things like "dual numbers" this should be quite accessible.

Comment: Ah, I see, of the form $a+bj+ck=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 0 & a & b \\
 0 & 0 & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$, yes?

Comment: @Anixx Yes, that is one representation of such an algebra.